# How to prevent elements from causing scrolling

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I am trying to create a simple black box that spans the top of my web page.

Currently I have this:

```
<canvas id="block" align="center" height="250" width="5000" 
style="border:1px solid #000000;background:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:-100px;z-index:10;">
```

Initially I tried making it a percentage, but it's far too complex for me.

I need to prevent the box from causing the page to scroll to the sides.

I'm sure this is a very simple thing, probably the main issue I am having is not knowing what to search for.
I have been googling for 2 hours now.

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:hidden;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can simply use `overflow:hidden`
example:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:200px;position:relative;"></div>
```

Watch the demo: [**jsFiddle Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/n5979/1/)

Comment: That only enables overflow for inside of the canvas (i.e. nothing).

Comment: It didn't work. I even tried overflow="hidden" before style""

Comment: @plaguedoctor You can't use `overflow="hidden"` out of style, because overflow is a css property. you should use it like the example above with `:`, in `style` attribute.

Comment: It's still not working. I've done it exactly as said, putting my canvas inside div tags copied from the above post.

Comment: @plaguedoctor I think you should give your div width and height. answer edited.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. No idea why giving it dimensions would help. Are we reduced to trying anything/everything? I hope not

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me and providing so many answers siamak.a.m

Comment: @plaguedoctor answer edited again. `position:relative;` added. I hope it works. Check out the live demo.

Comment: As I suspected, it forced it underneath the image I had it positioned over

Comment: I can work with it from here tho. Pretty much got it working now
Thankyou so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a simple black box that spans the top of my web page.

If you're trying to accomplish this then all you need to do is the following:

```
<div style="background-color:#000;height:10px;width:100%;"></div>
```

and place it directly under your opening `<body>` tag.

I'm confused as to why you are setting `width:5000px;` on a canvas, if you're expecting to make a canvas element wider than the viewport and still not allow scrolling then you need to set `overflow:hidden` on the **body** element.

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The canvas will be animated. It needs to be able to tilt without the corners showing on the image underneath.
5k is wider than any monitor setup likely to access the site

Comment: Have you thought about putting the canvas inside a div, then setting the overflow of the div as hidden? Then you can make the canvas as big as you want, and it won't display any scrollbars. Just don't forget to center the canvas inside the div.

Answer (score -1):

If the unwanted scrolling is due to user pressing arrow keys in your application, then you should be telling the browser that *you* are handling the arrow keys yourself by executing:

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

in the handler for keyboard events.

Additionally `html {overflow: hidden}` might work too.